# Kotlin Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: kotlin, null

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: 
method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter result
at ru.kbais.kotlionprj.MainMapActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainMapActivity.kt:0)
at ru.kbais.kotlionprj.MainMapActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainMapActivity.kt:125)
```

Ошибка в строке `inner class ParserTask : AsyncTask<String, Int, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>>() {`

Пытаюсь парсить ответ от гугла и когда получаю ноль и прога ложится.

Карта:

```
class MainMapActivity: AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null
    internal var markerPoints = ArrayList<LatLng>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 16f))
        mMap!!.setOnMapClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener { latLng ->
            if (markerPoints.size > 1) {
                markerPoints.clear()
                mMap!!.clear()
            }
            markerPoints.add(latLng)
            val options = MarkerOptions()
            options.position(latLng)
            if (markerPoints.size == 1) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
            } else if (markerPoints.size == 2) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
            }
            mMap!!.addMarker(options)
            if (markerPoints.size >= 2) {
                val origin = markerPoints[0] as LatLng
                val dest = markerPoints[1] as LatLng
                val url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest)
                val downloadTask = DownloadTask()
                downloadTask.execute(url)
            }
        })
    }
    private inner class DownloadTask : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String): String {
            var data = ""
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0])
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString())
            }
            return data
        }
        override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            val parserTask = ParserTask()
            parserTask.execute(result)
        }
    }
     inner class ParserTask : AsyncTask<String, Int, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg jsonData: String): List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? {
            val jObject: JSONObject
            var routes: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? = null
            try {
                jObject = JSONObject(jsonData[0])
                val parser = DirectionsJSONParser()
                routes = parser?.parse(jObject)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return routes
        }
        override fun onPostExecute(result: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>) {
            var points: ArrayList<*>? = null
            var lineOptions: PolylineOptions? = null
            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
            for (i in result.indices) {
                var points: ArrayList<LatLng>? = null
                lineOptions = PolylineOptions()
                val path = result[i]
                for (j in path.indices) {
                    val point = path[j]
                    val lat = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(point["lat"])
                    val lng = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(point["lng"])
                    val position = LatLng(lat, lng)
                    points!!.add(position)
                }
                lineOptions.addAll(points)
                lineOptions.width(12f)
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED)
                lineOptions.geodesic(true)

            }
            mMap!!.addPolyline(lineOptions)
        }
    }
    private fun getDirectionsUrl(origin: LatLng, dest: LatLng): String {
        val str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude
        val str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude
        val sensor = "sensor=false"
        val mode = "mode=driving"
        val parameters = "$str_origin&$str_dest&$sensor&$mode"
        val output = "json"
        return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/$output?$parameters"
    }
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun downloadUrl(strUrl: String): String {
        var data = ""
        var iStream: InputStream? = null
        var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null
        try {
            val url = URL(strUrl)
            urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConnection.connect()
            iStream = urlConnection.inputStream
            val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(iStream!!))
            val sb = StringBuffer()
            var line = ""
            line.lineSequence().forEach {
                sb.append(line)
            }
            data = sb.toString()
            br.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString())
        } finally {
            iStream!!.close()
            urlConnection!!.disconnect()
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

Парсер:

```
class DirectionsJSONParser {
    fun parse(jObject: JSONObject): List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        val routes = ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>()
        var jRoutes: JSONArray? = null
        var jLegs: JSONArray? = null
        var jSteps: JSONArray? = null
        try {
            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes")
            for (i in 0 until jRoutes!!.length()) {
                jLegs = (jRoutes.get(i) as JSONObject).getJSONArray("legs")
                val path = ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()
                for (j in 0 until jLegs!!.length()) {
                    jSteps = (jLegs.get(j) as JSONObject).getJSONArray("steps")
                    for (k in 0 until jSteps!!.length()) {
                        var polyline = ""
                        polyline = ((jSteps.get(k) as JSONObject).get("polyline") as JSONObject).get("points") as String
                        val list = decodePoly(polyline)
                        for (l in list.indices) {
                            val hm = HashMap<String, String>()
                            hm.put("lat", java.lang.Double.toString((list[l] as LatLng).latitude))
                            hm.put("lng", java.lang.Double.toString((list[l] as LatLng).longitude))
                            path.add(hm)
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
        return routes
    }
    private fun decodePoly(encoded: String): List<*> {

        val poly = ArrayList<LatLng>()
        var index = 0
        val len = encoded.length
        var lat = 0
        var lng = 0
        while (index < len) {
            var b: Int
            var shift = 0
            var result = 0
            do {
                b = encoded[index++].toInt() - 63
                result = result or (b and 0x1f shl shift)
                shift += 5
            } while (b >= 0x20)
            val dlat = if (result and 1 != 0) (result shr 1).inv() else result shr 1
            lat += dlat

            shift = 0
            result = 0
            do {
                b = encoded[index++].toInt() - 63
                result = result or (b and 0x1f shl shift)
                shift += 5
            } while (b >= 0x20)
            val dlng = if (result and 1 != 0) (result shr 1).inv() else result shr 1
            lng += dlng

            val p = LatLng(lat.toDouble() / 1E5,
                    lng.toDouble() / 1E5)
            poly.add(p)
        }
        return poly
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос то?

Comment: ну..программа ложится.А ложится не должна... ее надо научить нормально читать и обрабатывать json от гугла для построения пути по точкам на карте. но при построение второй точки и расчете пути она падает так как получаю неправильное значения. Как это поправить я хз.

Answer (score 1):

У вас сигнатура метода такая

```
fun onPostExecute(result: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>)
```

а передается в него, то что возвращает

```
fun doInBackground(vararg jsonData: String): List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?
```

Отсюда и `Parameter specified as non-null is null`